# Get x. value of "Linear Congruential Generator"

Tags: algorithm

I have a "Linear Congruential Generator", that generates random keys for my 2. faze Auth. I basically need to have a seed from that I will generate a key both in the client and on the server so I don't have to send it.

The problem is if the user won't use the client for a long time it will have to generate a lot of keys before it gets to the current key. The formula is 
`s1 = (a * s0 + 2) mod m` and i need nth member of this sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, LCG for Authentication, really? This looks like a bad idea to me...

But whatever, back to the question:

```
s(i+1) = (a*s(i) + 2) mod m
s(i+2) = (a*(a*s(i) + 2) + 2) mod m = a^2*s(i) + 2*(a+1) mod m
s(i+4) = (a^2*(a^2*s(i) + a*2+2) + a*2+2) mod m = a^4*s(i) + 2*(a^3+a^2+a+1) mod m
```

and via recursion

```
s(i+2^n) = a^2^n * s(i) + 2*(a^2^n-1)/(a-1)
```

Then to fast forward `n` steps, just write `n` in binary, and use the above formulas to do it in `log_2(n)` steps.

Comment: It's just for school purposes only. I don't intend to use it somewhere else, so it doesn't matter, what type of pseudo-random generator I will use.

Comment: I will mark it as answer right after I test it works :)

Comment: This answer is good, but I think the final formula is valid for any n, not only powers of two, so it would be clearer if it were written in terms of `n`, not `2^n`. You need the binary representation of `n` only for efficient exponentiation by squaring. (And when you calculate `a^n` with module arithmetic, you should calculate `(a^n) mod (m*(a - 1)`, so that the division works.).